# Fedora 17 Freezes on Macbook Pro Install

Tags: fedora, system-installation, macintosh

So I put Fedora on my flash drive using [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) tutorial, and I also burned it onto a DVD. Whenever I try to boot from it or one of the EFI boots, the countdown on the install freezes at 0. whenever I try to press a key, it doesn't do anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge Fedora 17 does not have complete support for EFI while I can't be certain I've had success using [This](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) utility to boot alternative operating systems on my mac. That one has been out of development for a while so [this one](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) might be a better choice

Comment: When I tried that, it still didn't work. The boot just hasn't worked.